# jQuery - With click of a link copy all classes from one element to another

Tags: jquery, class, copy, click, element

(see jsfiddle example)

When the ".link_to_rule_them_all" is clicked i would like to copy all the '.link_to_rule_them_all span' classes into #box and clear the '#box' between every click.

my example code and the explanation is here http://jsfiddle.net/znCmq/2/

As you can see i have no idea about the js of this.. any ideas? eh..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$('.link_to_rule_them_all').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#box').attr('class', ($('span', $(this)).attr('class')));
});
```

live example : http://jsfiddle.net/moeishaa/3t33d/

Comment: ya i know, .click is just a wrapper for bind i think

Comment: sorry, i wasnt sure if it mattered but heres update on the code.. theres supposed to be multiple links and one box element.. the problem seems to be that it never clears out the classes in between.. it just keeps adding.. http://jsfiddle.net/DfXUU/2/ get what i mean?

Comment: yea sorry for deleting my post...it is just a wrapper, but you can save your users loading time if you minimize your code...those little details build up into saving you a couple of kilobytes.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
<a class="link_to_rule_them_all" href="javascript://">

$('.link_to_rule_them_all').click(function() {
 $('#box').attr('class',$(this).attr('class'))    
})
```

It's proper form to use a null href instead of a hash.

Comment: If the HREF points somewhere you'll be taken to another page, so you won't be seeing what's going on with this one.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can add the listener directly to the span like this:

```
$('span').click(function(e) {
```

Then you can add the class attribute to the DIV

```
$('#box').append($(e.target).attr('class'));
```

Ok let's try this then

```
$('.link_to_rule_them_all').click(function(e) {
//if you wanna attribute the span classes to the #box as classes
var box = $('#box')
box.removeClass();
box.addClass($(this).children('span').attr('class'));
})
```

If you wanna add the span class as TEXT:

```
$('.link_to_rule_them_all').click(function(e) {
var box = $('#box');
box.text();
box.append($(this).children('span').attr('class'));
)}
```

Comment: i put the link there for a reason though.. also i update the first post saying that '#box' element should be cleared between each click.. otherwise it just keeps adding to it.. right?

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to be rude.  I updated something else i'm not sure if it will fit but you got 2 more options.